# Team Foundation Server 2008 password change breaks Team System Sharepoint service

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

To comply with a new password policy, I've had to change domain passwords on our Team Foundation Server 2008 box and also the build agent box.

I've now managed to get TFS working normally (work item tracking, source control etc) by using the TFSAdmin command to change the Team Foundation server account password, and my development team can once again all use that normally.

However when I try to create a new Team Project I get the following error message:

> Error  Unable to connect to the Windows SharePoint Services at
> devserver2
>
> Explanation  The Project Creation Wizard was not able to connect to
> the Windows SharePoint Services at devserver2. The reason for the
> failed connection cannot be determined at this time. Because the
> connection failed, the wizard was not able to complete creating the
> Windows SharePoint Services site

The only things that have changed are the domain passwords. All the Windows Sharepoint services on that machine appear to be working.

The Event log shows the following error:

> ## 50071: Unable to connect to the database WSS_Config_f6496d3cb3884ed1a323b572de037b89 on DEVSERVER2.

but the database server is running and Studio Manager can see the databases, which all have dbowner privileges for the domain account TFSSERVICE.

What step(s) have I missed?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualy in old TFS 2008 environments, the Sharepoint environment also uses the TFSSERVICE as the service account for the application pool. If the server hasn't restarted yet (or sharepoint was still running, it's still using the old credentials (which are invalid) to log on to the database. If you reboot the server/service most of the time the services won't get back up. In order to fix this, just reset the stored credentials within sharepoint using: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838